# Pull a desired value (integer) from a string, that is inbetween two underscores

Tags: string, python-2.7, for-loop

Strange one, I have lots of folders named for example:

141110_0.7_armt_amb2_4_load_haut_pag_-40.74_75.06_

or

141110_0.7_armt_amb2_5_load_haut_pag_-40.74_75.06_

I want to pull the integer value (in the first case 4, second case 5) from the folder name and store it somewhere (doesnt matter where).

However strings are immutable so I dont know a good way of doing this.

Is it even possible considering there are the other numbers in the way eg. 0.7 and the ones at the end??

The integers in the folders range from 0-11, which is annoying as maybe if it was just 0-9 it might be simpler to pull.

I will offer some code but I really don't think it will help...

```
name = '141110_0.35_armt_amb2_0_load_pag_'

for i in name:
    if name[i-1] & name[i+1] == '_':
        a = name[i]
```

Thats why I tried but like I said strings are immutable so it doesnt work.

Any suggestions would be great.. (Y)

Comment: Split the string on `_` then take the 4th index from the result. You didn't post what language you're using, you should tag the question as such.

Comment: sorry! ya its python

Comment: Thank you, very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Python, so you'd use:

`foo = name.split('_')[4]`